# Visualforce Charting: Line Chart Intervals with Dates

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

I have a custom object, `MrCustomObject__c`, which I am making into an `apex:chart`.

`Mr_Custom_Object__c` has a Date field, `Date__c`, and a Number field, `Number__c`.

The Dates should go along the x-axis and the numbers along the y-axis.

I have a wrapper class, `AxisDataWrapper`, that controls the data in the chart.

```
public class AxisDataWrapper{

    public String date {get;set;}
    public Integer number {get;set;}

    public AxisDataWrapper(String date, Integer number){

        this.date = date;
        this.number= number;        
    }   
}
```

So let's say I create three `AxisDataWrapper`s, `[2012-11-01, 1]`, `[2012-11-03, 2]`, `[2012-12-25, 3]`.

Ideally I would want the x-axis to be a proper scale.  I.e., `AxisDataWrapper1` and `2` should be close to each other, and `AxisDataWrapper3` further away.

Unfortunately, as this is a String, Visualforce obviously has no way of knowing what the intervals should be.  I tried creating new empty `AxisDataWrapper`, `[2012-11-02, null]` but it complained it did not find a Number.

Here's the Chart VF code:

```
<apex:chart height="400" width="700" data="{!axisData}">
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="number" minimum="-2" maximum="2"
        steps="7" grid="true"/>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="date"/>
    <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" xField="date" yField="number"
        markerType="circle" markerSize="3" markerFill="#FF0000"/>
</apex:chart>
```

As you can see, the x-axis type is Category because it's a String.  But I thought, what if I made it Numeric and instead of a String in the AxisDataWrapper, I used a Date?  Then I would get the appropriate x-axis scale.

This is what happened:

[image: sample chart]

So, I'm kind of caught in the middle here, wanting my Dates to have a scale, but wanting that scale to make sense.  Is there any way out?

Comment: I have this similar issue. Did you found a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, I did the conversion in Javascript.  See my new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following JS function to convert Milliseconds to Dates when the chart had loaded

```
$('span[id$="myChartInner"] tspan').each(function(){

     var text = $(this).text();

         var milli = parseInt($(this).text());
         var d = new Date(milli);
         var month = d.getUTCMonth()+1;
         var day = d.getUTCDate();
         var year = d.getYear().toString().slice(1);

         var newdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;                      
         $(this).text(newdate);

         $(this).attr('x', parseInt($(this).attr('x')) + 30);



});
```

Answer (score 4):

When we looked at `apex:chart` before it went GA in Winter '12, we weren't able to find a way to do date-based charts.  As a result, we ended up using the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) instead.

Here's a [Developerforce page on integrating with Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Google_Visualizations).

I highly recommend this route -- we've been able to create great line graphs that are scaled as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try playing with `<apex:chartLabel>` - you'd use your numerics to make sure you have gaps but another field (possibly this date formatted to string) as the labels visible on the axis. I believe all of these have to be real fields in your wrapper, trick with `String getLabel() { return dt.format(); }` throws errors to the JS console.

I'm upvoting Tom's answer by the way - Visualforce charts are generally available but I cant exactly call them production quality... Using Google charts sounds safer for now.

Or you can patiently generate your gaps /spacers with records that have date filled in but null values ;)